# Uniquely Identify ImageButtons placed Programmatically

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have been placing several ImageButtons programmatically in a TableLayout, every ImageButton has it's own Drawable resource as a Background.
I use an XML description for the layout of the ImageButton itself and afterwards use the LayoutInflater to retrieve such an ImageButton (called genre_cell.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageButton
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/genreCellItemId" android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="5dip" android:paddingRight="5dip">
</ImageButton>
```

And in my class I do :

```
myButton = (ImageButton) inflater.inflate(R.layout.genre_cell, row, false);
```

I have actually attached an onClickListener on every ImageButton, but now I'd like to uniquely identify which ImageButton has been clicked...
I thought that maybe I could somehow retrieve the Drawable's ID used for the background and check that one with the available Drawable's int values ?
Is this an option and if so how should it be implemented ?
Also are there any other options ?

Comment: You should accept your own answer if that definitely worked for you. That lets everyone else know the problem is solved, particularly useful for anyone else who comes to this question looking for a solution.

Comment: I'd love to Steve, but I have to wait 2 days before I can accept my own answer, or at least that's what the pop-up tells me when I try to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By chance I just came across a blog which was mentioning the setTag() and getTag() methods for the ImageButton,
those I can use and thus is my question answered...
Link to the blog :
http://jongladwin.blogspot.com/2010/03/androidsettag-and-gettag-usage-for.html

After some looking around I even saw the setId() method and the getId() method, so it looks like there are several methologies to identify such an ImageButton... good to know :P

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can!

in your `res/values` folder, create an xml file `button_ids.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
  <item type="id" name="image_button_one" />
  <item type="id" name="image_button_two" />
  ...
</resources>
```

then after your inflate call:

```
myButton = (ImageButton) inflater.inflate(R.layout.genre_cell, row, false);
myButton.setId(R.id.image_button_one);
...
```

I haven't actually tried that, but I think this is how you're supposed to do it.

Comment: hhmmm that means I should keep specific track of every button I have had and already have given an id ? 
Also the amount of buttons is NOT given, it can range betwoon 0 and probably about 80... I won't be making a resource file with 80 item's in it :P
You should immagine that setId somewhere in a loop of 80 items, so the R.id.image_button_one should dinamically change to image_button-two etc up to button_eighty...

Comment: ah well, then it probably doesn't make much sense. If it was only a hand-full, then this would be the way to go, however.